# Which should we use?'Can' or 'could'?

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal, can-modal

Is it possible to use **'can'** instead of **'could'** in this sentence?

> It encouraged me to bring my old coats for the homeless so that they **could** stay warm.

Answer (score 2):

You can if their being able to stay warm has relevance to the present moment, otherwise you use the past tense.